# Using the right-hand side of "Yacas vector" after Solve as a function

Tags: r

I am trying to solve an optimization problem using two equations. But the derivative of the first equation will be used in the second equation. As you can see below, I need something between c and d. c set the first derivative equal to zero and bring y to the right-hand side, and the y is used in the second equation.

```r
x <- Sym("x")

y <- Sym("y")

a <- function(x, y) (60-x-y)*y

b <- Deriv(a, "y")

c <- Solve(b(x, y)==0, y); c #Need something here to extract just the left-hand side (60 - x)/2; it produces "Yacas vector:[1] y == (60 - x)/2"

y <-  function(x) (60 - x)/2

f <- function(x) (60-x-y(x))*x

optimize(f, c(1,100), maximum=TRUE)
```

I need something that will extract just the right-hand side "(60 - x)/2" and use it as a function.

Comment: In which package is the `Deriv` function from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is asking for *something that will extract just the right-hand side "(60 - x)/2" and use it as a function* .

```
library(Ryacas)

x <- Sym("x")
y <- Sym("y")

a <- function(x, y) (60-x-y)*y
s <- Solve(deriv(a(x, y), y) == 0, y)

da <- function(x) {}
body(da) <- parse(text = sub("list(y == ", "(", as.character(s), fixed = TRUE))

da
## function (x) 
## ((60 - x)/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
x <- Sym("x")
y <- Sym("y")
a <- (60-x-y)*y
b <- deriv(a, y)
c <- Solve(b==0, y)
yacas(paste0("y Where ", c))
# expression((60 - x)/2)
```

To define the function:

```
f <- function(x){}
body(f) <- yacas(paste0("y Where ", c))$text
```